# I turn off my computer, and eclipse deleted all the content inside the files

Tags: eclipse

I was building an android app. My PC was really slow and I turn my PC off, Eclipse was running, and I forgot to close it, but i saved my project.

I turn my pc ON again, and when I tried to open my project, eclipse deleted all the folders. I checked the workspace folder, and all files were empty, including the Java files, there is no way to have my code back, i don't have backups.

I tried to recover the system three times, but it didn't work, it failed. I installed a lot of softwares to recover deleted files, but i had no success. I'm really sad.

What do i do?

Comment: Learn from your mistakes. Use git or mercurial.

Comment: Git or anyother VCS cannot be used as a solution to this. People dont want unstable code to commit in VCS just to prevent from this eclipse behaviour. Is this a bug in eclipse ? Any reference.